# Qemu: issues with bridged networking (Linux host, OpenBSD guest)

Tags: linux, openbsd, qemu

I have a computer running Linux.
It has qemu installed.
It has a bridge interface **br0** configured with the following settings:

```
IP: 10.1.1.1
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
```

There is also a **tap0** interface that is added to **br0**. **tap0** is supposed to be used for networking guests running inside qemu.

I'm running Slax Linux from its LiveCD inside qemu like this:

```
qemu -kernel-kqemu \
 -net nic,vlan=0,macaddr=aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa,model=pcnet \
 -net tap,vlan=0,ifname=tap0,script=/etc/qemu-ifup \
 -m 512 \
 -cdrom slax-6.0.7.iso \
 1>stdout.log 2>stderr.log
```

I'm booting Slax in text mode (don't need X, because my goal is to test networking). I'm configuring the network interface in the guest like this:

```
IP: 10.1.1.4
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 10.1.1.1
```

Everything works well, I can ping in both directions:

```
10.1.1.1 -> 10.1.1.4
10.1.1.4 -> 10.1.1.1
```

Now I'm replacing the Slax LiveCD with a qemu image, that contains a freshly installed OpenBSD 4.5. I run it like this:

```
qemu -kernel-kqemu \
 -net nic,vlan=0,macaddr=aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa,model=pcnet \
 -net tap,vlan=0,ifname=tap0,script=/etc/qemu-ifup \
 -m 512 \
 -hda obsd.img \
 1>stdout.log 2>stderr.log
```

OpenBSD boots, I'm configuring its network interface exactly the same way:

```
IP: 10.1.1.4
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 10.1.1.1
```

Now I can't ping in any direction.

The qemu logs don't contain any hints.

Also this is not a firewalling issue: OpenBSD 4.5 doesn't have pf enabled by default. Snippet from its **/etc/rc.conf**:

```
pf=NO # Packet filter / NAT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a [known regression](http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2009-07/msg01593.html) in QEMU Versions including, but not limited to 0.10.4 and 0.10.5. Aparrently, using model=rtl8139 and QEMU 0.9.1 works, so you might want to try that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think openbsd will work out your default route by its self

You can check using route show -inet

You should get something like:
bash-3.2# route show -inet 
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags   Refs      Use   Mtu  Prio Iface
default            10.1.1.1           UGS        1  1600975     -    48 em0 
...

If its working correctly, if default isn't there then you need to add 10.1.1.1 to /etc/mygate so it adds it on boot and manually create the route using

route add default gw 10.1.1.1

Comment: I'm doing it exactly like that: have "10.1.1.1" in /etc/mygate and "inet 10.1.1.4 255.255.255.0" in /etc/hostname.pcn0. "ifconfig pcn0" shows that the NIC is configured properly. Also "route -n show | grep 10.1.1.1" finds the default route in the routing table.